# Volume+Caustics?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency, volumetrics, glass

Is there any way to make caustics work in a volumetric environment? When using the Cycles render engine, light passing through a Glass BSDF in a volumetric world will not show through on the other side (see photo)[image: The black bar in the middle is a glass wall, the whole environment is volumetric.]

No matter what I have ever tried, glass always blocks light like this. And as an FYI:

1. All caustics are enabled
2. Many light bounces were used
3. Rendered on GPU (CPU does not work either)

Comment: This is a known limitation of Cycles. Try LuxRender (LuxCore Bidir mode) if you want to stay with opensource, or else Octane, Thea, Indigo, etc. you name it.